# Не работает Mediaplayer в Android

Tags: android

Я делал звуки через Mediaplayer, сделал все правильно,  ошибок при сборке не было. Но эмулятор просто зависает. Если попробовать убрать строчку с нахождением файла с звуком "test = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.df);", то эмулятор стабильно работает. В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Mediaplayer в Android Studio работать и не должен - он должен работать в Андроид эмуляторе или устройстве. По существу: зависает - это значит ни на что не реагирует и его приходится прибивать через систему - так? Или просто не играет? Для решения проблемы мало информации - покажите код, логи (если в них есть что-то красное и подозрительное), какой тип файла пытаетесь воспроизвести?

Comment: Так и на эмуляторе он и не работает. Он вообще в начале пустой экран показывает и ничего не грузит. Скриншоты вот: https://drive.google.com/open?id=14ifamU_ptnUdje7MQbMoWkgx9vSe9jw8 https://drive.google.com/open?id=1nRq4yt9xsLCpAeezOWZGlswvubo8f4yQ

Comment: Здравствуйте! Попробовал запустить на телефоне - работает. А на эмуляторе нет. Что делать?